# How to build electron app using angular 2

Tags: angular, electron

I am pretty new to angular2, TS and electron and want to start making a native app using electron and angular2, however, still, I have not 100% achieve that.
following is what I have done after installing angular, TS:

1. clone angular quickstart seed from their official website and removed unwanted files
2. install electron and its typing for my project
3. create a separate folder under src for electron and defined main.ts for electron (which is responsible for creating electron app window and managing electron app lifecycle, this main is separate from angular's main.ts in root folder)
4. in system.config.js I have made an entry inside **map** property for electron to be able to import it(I am not sure if this step is required since electron is not a library and it is a framework, so I suppose electron should be always available and I need to import electron's component from it)
5. in package.json's start script I have added a script to lead the app in electron shel `"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\" \"electron src/electron/main.js\"",`

but I do not know how to access electron's API inside angular's component, any help will be appreciated

**UPDATE**

I have included package.json file for information such as entry point versions , script and etc

```
{
"name": "angular-quickstart",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc -p src/",
"build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
"build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
"serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
"serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
"prestart": "npm run build",
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\" \"electron src/electron/main.js\"",
"electron": "electron",
"pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
"e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
"preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
"protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
"pretest": "npm run build",
"test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
"pretest:once": "npm run build",
"test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
"lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
"@types/electron": "^1.4.35",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"electron": "^1.6.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"systemjs": "0.19.40",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^3.2.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.2",
"typescript": "~2.1.0",
"canonical-path": "0.0.2",
"tslint": "^3.15.1",
"lodash": "^4.16.4",
"jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
"karma": "^1.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~4.0.14",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4",
"@types/node": "^6.0.46",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
 },
"repository": {}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

not easy to point where is wrong, need to see all your files and structure

but check [Angular4Election](https://github.com/Longfld/Angular4Electron)  this is angular quickstart with election